# Terminology in higher dimensional linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, terminology

Given that $y=kx+d$ is called a linear relationship, are there established naming conventions when more variables are concerned?

The linear equation can be generalized by $b + \sum a_ix_i = 0$ and the result should be a hyperplane. In the 2D case mentioned at the beginning, such a hyperplane is a line and I assume that linear relationship is derived from that. In the 3D case $z = ax + by +c$, the hyperplane  results in a simple plane ([example drawing](https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter/?expression=2x%2B3y%2B4&xRange=-50%2C%2050&yRange=-50%2C%2050&resolution=25)), is that relationship called planar, analogous to the linear example?

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work